# Filter by shared reference

Tags: views

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I have a content type of "School."
I have a content type of "Event" that contains an entity reference to "School" so that events can be linked to schools.
I can create a view block that filters by the school, when the block is placed on the node of the school, using contextual filters.

The problem:
Starting with the built-in "Basic Page," I added an entity reference to "School" so that "Basic Pages" can be linked to a "School," and be subpages of the "School."
How do I filter a view of "Events" that when placed on a "Basic Page" the "Events" block view will filter based on the entity reference, "Schools," that is shared between the "Event" and "Basic Page?"  I am looking to have an "Events" subpage that lists all the events of that individual school.
I am trying to avoid having to create separate block views that use filter criteria of each individual school.  I was hoping to use contextual filters.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, at least in D8 use "reverse entity references" in contextual filters and relationships, so what you propose should work.

Have a contextual reference grabbing the node id of the Basic page from the URL. A relationship from the page to the school comes next, then a reverse relationship looking for items that have a relationship to the School. You'll also add a filter on that second relationship, limiting it to Events.

Comment: a little more help please.
My entity reference on both "Events" and "Page" is LINK TO SCHOOL.
First Relationship - field_link_to_school:Content (Appears in: article, page, event)
Second Relationship - field_link_to_school (Relate each Content with a field_link_to_school set to content item.) AND this has a relationship back to the first relationship.  Everything seems good to start when I filter to "Event." Events that are related to any school displays.  But when I add a contextual filter to node id nothing will display on the page.
[Imgur](https://imgur.com/76fH2jw)

Comment: In the contextual filter you need to set "when the filter value is not available" to provide a default as the content ID from the URL. You can test by putting in an appropriate id in the preview box.

Comment: I did that but now realized that for the contextual filter, I needed to use the reference.  Thank you @beltouche

Comment: Sorry, just tested and it does not completely filter out by School, just by content type of Event.  Events with a LINK TO SCHOOL is another school still show.

Comment: As I noted in main response, you'll need to add filters on the related entities. Can you post another image of the settings you have so far? Especially the contextual filters and relationships.

Comment: [Relationship 1](https://imgur.com/yjBoQze)
[Relationship 2](https://imgur.com/oFCvrKV)
[Contextual Filter](https://imgur.com/PS0f29l)
This contextual filter does not display any results.

Comment: Those all look good. (It's hard to tell from Views' UI the difference between a reverse and regular entity relationship, but your previous description sounds right.) You mean to say if you put the id of a page into the preview box and click update preview you don't get what you want? You get nothing? Or you get all Events?

Comment: Finally, I got it.  For some reason, the preview in views was not displaying.  When I went to the actual pages with the view it displayed correctly.  Thank you.